# Launch the compass app from within iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying something like this to launch the compass from within my app:

```
    NSString *stringURL = @"compass://";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

does anyone know the correct url to use to launch the compass app?

http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes - I'm using this as a reference, but nothing about the compass is posted.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick look at Compas.app's Info.plist shows no declaration of custom URL type, which means there is no public way to open it from your app, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The compas app does not have an app URL.

Answer (score 1):

*does anyone know the correct url to use to launch the compass app?*

What makes you think there is one?

I do not believe the compass app registers any [URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW26). This is completely optional from the developers point of view and is not implemented for all applications.