# Open the apple compass app from within my react native application

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there a way to open the apple compass from within my app?

I came across the following question: [Launch the compass app from within iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980813/launch-the-compass-app-from-within-iphone-app),  but its really old so hoping maybe there is a way now.

I can link the app using this code and that opens app store even though compass is installed:

```
AppLink.maybeOpenURL(
  'itms-apps://apps.apple.com/us/app/compass/id1067456176',
  {
    appName: 'compass',
    appStoreId: 'id1067456176',
    appStoreLocale: 'gb'
  })
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `appStoreId: '1067456176',` <-- remove "id" from the string

Comment: Unfortunately that still opens the compass in the app store even though it is installed on the phone.  Apparently Apple hasn't provided the URL scheme for the compass app so there's no way to link it. Is that true? Is there any place i find the URL scheme for apps ?